# Is it possible to provably make cryptocurrency tokens inaccessible?

Tags: public-key, cryptocurrency

Would it be possible to generate an agreed upon public key that has no corresponding private key (maybe by using the latest few block hashes of a blockchain) and then send cryptocurrency to that account to provably make your tokens inaccessible?

If so, this would be a really easy way to implement cross-chain exchange of value.

Comment: It's possible to reserve a particular public key for a conventional purpose; or a particular bitstring that's the size of a public key, but not a valid one. Either is possible with ECDSA for secp256k1 that's common in bitcoin. If the cryptcurrency uses the words _public key_ to designate a hash of a true public key: designate by _reserved public key_ that hash of the reserved true public key. The rest is a matter of convention of the particular cryptocurrency, thus off-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Also this [meta](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/985/555).

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks for the comment! I thought my idea made sense (since public keys are derived from private keys), but I wanted to ask just to be sure. I wasn't completely sure whether this kind of question fit this subexchange, but I saw the cryptocurrency tag and read in the pop-up that "cryptographic mechanisms" were allowed.